# Unable to add a new column to SQL Server table with TIMESTAMP data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing SQL Server table with the data type of `TIMESTAMP`.

This is my script:

```
ALTER TABLE OrderDetails 
    ADD ModifiedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

It should be not null. Running this script results in an error

> Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp

I tried executing it without `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But then it says

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ModifiedTime'

Any advises please?

Comment: Just a minor note that the default values will be used only in the case of insertion of new data so it will be better to name the column as CreatedTime(or At) instead of modifiedTime. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server has **absolutely nothing** to do with date & time (thanks to Sybase for screwing that one up!) - it's just a system-internal, binary counter (often used for opmistic concurrency checks). It's been deprecated, too, and renamed `ROWVERSION` which is much clearer as to what it is.

For date & time - use `DATE` (if you need only date - no time), or `DATETIME2(n)`  datatypes:

```
ALTER TABLE OrderDetails 
    ADD ModifiedTime DATETIME2(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

See [the official Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details on date&time datatypes and functions

Comment: Great... Thank you very much. I did not know that TIMESTAMP has been deprecated. Will mark this as the answer.

Comment: This is very important for people coming from a MySql background.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution provided here: https://www.sql-server-performance.com/defaults-not-created-timestamp/

```
ALTER TABLE OrderDetails ADD ModifiedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have already tried this before. But the same error.